# Double pointer - getting unexpected output

Tags: c, pointers, double-pointer

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main()
{
    int a[3][3]={{0,1},{2,3},{5,6}},**b,i,j;
    b=(int **)calloc(3,sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        b[i]=(int *)calloc(3,sizeof(int));
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            b[i][j]=(i+1)*(j+1);
        }
    }

    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",*(*a+4),**a+4,*(*b+4),**b+4); 
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",*(a[2]-2),**(a+2),*(b[2]-2),**(b+2)); 

    return 0;
}
```

Output I am getting :

```
3 4 2 5
3 5 6 3
```

According to me I should be getting:

```
3 4 4 5
3 5 4 3
```

Reason:

`*(*b+4) = *(b[0]+4)`. `b[0]+4` points to `b[1][1]` so this value should be `4`, which is the value of matrix at `1,1` position

`*(b[2]-2)`, Now `b[2]-2` points to `b[1][1]`, so value again should be `4`

please tell me why am getting different output

Comment: Why do you think `b[0]+4` points to `b[1][1]`? You allocated each row separately, they're not contiguous.

Comment: All the rows of `a` are contiguous because it's a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: Try printing the values of `b[0]` and `b[1]` to see that they differ by more than `3`.

Comment: @Barmar I read calloc allocates contiguous memory?

Comment: Each call to `calloc()` allocates contiguous memory, but it's not contiguous with other calls.

Comment: @Barmar oh I see, so I am getting garbage values in both the places, right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a 2-dimensional array like `a[3][3]`, the entire array is contiguous, so `a[0][2]` is immediately followed by `a[1][0]`. When you use pointer arithmetic on `a`, you can depend on this ability to cross rows, as long as you stay within the entire `a` array.

But when you use an array of pointers, there's no reason to expect each row to be contiguous with the previous row. The memory allocated by each call to `malloc()` is unrelated to previous calls. Also, `malloc()` has to ensure that the memory is properly aligned for any datatype; if the size you're allocating is not a multiple of this, they can't possibly be contiguous. And many dynamic memory allocators store bookkeeping information (such as the size of the allocation, so that `free()` knows how much memory to reclaim) before the allocation, so that also prevents allocations from being contiguous.

It's undefined behavior to access the memory outside the allocation size. Since `b[0]` points to an allocation of 3 `int`, `b[0]+4` is outside this allocation, and `*(b[0]+4)` causes undefined behavior.